# Y axis proportions in histogram with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have prepared a dataset that I wish to display as a histogram.

I believe I get the X axis right, but can't seem to get `totmis1` on the Y axis... Just an unclear histogram:

```
ggplot(data = brfss2013a, aes(x = totmis)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: please provide more information. a [mcve] is preferable. read [ask] for details

Comment: I might have answered the wrong question; if so, please edit your question to clarify ...

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** use `geom_bar(stat="identity")` instead of `geom_histogram()`

I think the terminology you are looking for is a *bar chart* (technically, a histogram is the result of counting/binning a *continuous* distribution of data; it's not clear whether you've already computed these values by binning, or whether the data mean something else, but I don't think it matters).

```
dd <- data.frame(totmis=1:11,
                 totmis1=c(5786,5086,3187,2594,1591,1318,
                           847,754,512,511,383))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dd, aes(totmis,totmis1))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

You need `stat="identity"` because `geom_bar()` tries to count occurrences by default ...

[image]